# XNA References not found

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Whenever I create a new XNA project I get warnings telling me that the references that are added by default could not be found.

[image: Screenshot]
Here's the [link](http://puu.sh/59Bsf.png).

I tried deleting the references and creating them again but this didn't work as they were not on the list. I tried repairing my XNA install and also doing a clean install and this didn't work either.

I'm not sure what could have caused this because I haven't done anything in XNA for a long time and the last time I did, it worked fine.

Comment: Are you perhaps using Windows 8, or Visual Studio 2012/2013? It's possible to run XNA Studio on those but you must take some additional steps.

Comment: download the required refrences from web....it comes in .dll format

Comment: and then paste them ino refrences directory...where all other refrences are stored

Comment: I am using windows 7 with visual studio 2010. I have tried reinstalling both visual studio and xna framework. Surely the dll files would have come with the xna installation?

Comment: You could easily check that, you can find the XNA dlls here: [DRIVE]:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86. (for Windows x86)